# Revert text-styling (class) back to it's original CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `span` like this and styled as:

```html
<span class="spoiler" onclick="reveal()"> I am a sentence.</span>

.spoiler {
  background-color:#000000;
}

.spoiler:hover{
  background-color:transparent;
  }
```

Then I have some JS that modifies to permanently reveal the hidden text (truncated to show relevant part only):

```js
if ... {
        sentence.style.color = "#f00";
        sentence.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
    } else {
        sentence.style.color = "#000";
        sentence.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
    }
```

The problem is in the `else`. Once I click to revert back to the spoiler style, I can no longer `hover` over the text to reveal the sentence (as I could pre-click).

How to achieve this?

Comment: Since your changing style in javascript, your style becomes inline, specificity of inline style is more than class. Instead of apply css with style in javascript add/ remove class to that element and handle style in css file

Answer (score 1):

Instead of set style on span in 'if' add some class on it, and remove this class in 'else'. Or just remove style attribute in else.

Comment: Can you show a basic example how to do this?

Comment: if { sentense.classList.add("className") else { sentense.classList.remove("className"). In css .sentence.className { color: #f00; }, or else { sentence.removeAttribute("style").